# How can I add Webhooks from Stackoverflow

Tags: webhooks, slack, discord

I want to listen to any updates from StackOverflow in Discord/Gitter, just like GitHub Repository Webhooks sending events to Discord/Slack.

Is it possible to create webhooks in StackOverflow to POST to Discord/Gitter?

### Update on 2018-04-19

Found a workaround to active polling SO at a interval, by sending GET to /events this [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/events).

It's better to use pubsub style to be notified by SO, kindly advice for improvements.